# Does Perforce support files with only capitalization differences?

Tags: perforce

Two files ended up in my Perforce Depot with different content, but only capitalization differences to their names:

//depot/path/to/file/readme.txt

//depot/path/to/file/README.txt

I am getting strange behavior from P4V on both Windows and Linux when I map these files to a workspace.

Is this a known limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so much a limitation, as a feature.  Yes, perforce does support content with only capitalization differences.

I think the simple answer is that if your server is running on Linux, it is supported.  If your server is running on windows it is not.

There is a way to disable it if you are running a Linux server and find it undesirable.

More details on case sensitivity [here](https://kb.perforce.com/P4dServerReference/CaseSensitiv..forceServer/CaseSensitivity)

[Instructions](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Switching-the-Perforce-server-from-case-insensitive-mode-C1-to-case-sensitive-mode) for turning on case sensitivity on a UNIX server

How to [determine](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Determining-if-the-Server-is-Running-with-the-C1-Flag/?l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle) if the server is case sensitive

Moving from case sensitive to case insensitive is obviously more tricky, as there is a potential for name collisions.  In that case, you probably need to contact perforce support.

Comment: Perfect response @jgritty!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Does it make sense to you that a windows P4V client connecting to a Linux server running in case sensative mode would only sync one of the two files locally?

Comment: You link above answered my question (https://kb.perforce.com/P4dServerReference/CaseSensitiv..forceServer/CaseSensitivity) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, windows clients will only get one of the files.  P4V can see both, and you can force sync either one, but they will overwrite, because the Windows filesystem puts them in the same place.